# Visualstudio.com - Team services PowerShell

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, team-explorer-everywhere

We started to use Team service on visualstudio.com for our versioning control.
As I don't intend to install vs2015 on the server, how can I download the latest version on the server from the Team service?

compiling and publishing on the server is easy

Comment: you should probably not have TFS or a TFS build agent on any prod server, you can however use a TFS build agent, set up with appropriate permissions, to be able to deploy to a server.  There are plenty of tutorials for this.  There are also pieces of software which make things like this easier.  MS Build, TeamCity, and Octopus deploy just to name a few.

Comment: Do you success download the latest version through tf.exe?

Answer (score 1):

When you install the VSTS Build & Release Agent from VSTS it will include tf.exe, which is all that's needed to map and download sources from the commandline. An alternative to installing the agent is to install [Team Explorer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=40776) (stand-alone download would be 2013) or download the [Cross Platform TFS Commandline](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47727) tools.

You can also download the [TFS Client Object Model](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/14.102.0) through Nuget and call it directly from PowerShell.

As far as I can tell there is no stand-alone download of the TFS/VSTS commandline tool (`tf.exe`).